# How to split string at decimal place in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

According to Rules when I round up and round down string the `output` is like this.

1.41 -> 1.40
1.49 -> 1.50

But it's a bit different in my case: I want  my string to round down always like if string is 1.46 I want to get 1.40.

Comment: The answer to your header question is NSString's componentsSeparatedByString:@".", but you're better served with Igor's answer.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `floor`

```
let foo = floor(1.49 * 10) / 10
print(foo) //1.4

let bar = floor(6.71 * 10) / 10
print(bar) //6.7
```

Comment: suppose my value is 6.71 ,than i want to round down like 6.70 even if value is 1.49 i want to down it to 1.40.

Comment: yes, you can get it, using `floor`

Comment: Thanks bro.its working